# Can't fetch data from Sanity to next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js, frontend, sanity

I'm currently learning Next.js and have gone through one blog tutorial with the Sanity plug-in. But I get an error and I can't figure out why(

[Screenthot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nNWQ.jpg)

Here is the error that is displayed in the console:

```
Failed to load content for webpack://react-devtools-extensions/react-devtools-shared/src/backend/console.js (Fetch through target failed: Unsupported URL scheme; Fallback: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME)
```

I will be very grateful for help and explanation!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.